# Inconsistencies between caseInsensitiveCompare: vs isCaseSensitiveLike:

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I was wondering if anyone could explain this seemingly weird behavior?

```
NSString *emptyString = @"";
NSString *aBunchOfAsterisks = @"*********";

NSLog(@"NSString's caseInsensitiveCompare: says the two strings are %@", [emptyString caseInsensitiveCompare:aBunchOfAsterisks] == NSOrderedSame ? @"EQUAL" : @"NOT EQUAL");
NSLog(@"NSComparisonMethods protocol's isCaseInsensitiveLike: says aBunchOfAsterisks is %@ to emptyString", [emptyString isCaseInsensitiveLike:aBunchOfAsterisks] ? @"EQUAL" : @"NOT EQUAL");
NSLog(@"NSComparisonMethods protocol's isCaseInsensitiveLike: says emptyString is %@ to aBunchOfAsterisks", [aBunchOfAsterisks isCaseInsensitiveLike:emptyString]? @"EQUAL" : @"NOT EQUAL");
```

which logs the following

> NSString's caseInsensitiveCompare: says the two strings are NOT EQUAL
>   NSComparisonMethods protocol's isCaseInsensitiveLike: says
>   aBunchOfAsterisks is EQUAL to emptyString
>    NSComparisonMethods
>   protocol's isCaseInsensitiveLike: says emptyString is NOT EQUAL to 
>   aBunchOfAsterisks

Why is the second comparison method, namely

```
[emptyString isCaseInsensitiveLike:aBunchOfAsterisks];
```

return YES? even worse, this seems to happen only if the character is '*****'. Any other value in **aBunchOfAsterisks** and all 3 ways of comparing, return **NO**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the header:

```
// argument should be a string using simple shell wildcards (* and ?).
// (e.g. "Stev*" or "N?XT").
// Returns NO if receiver is not an NSString.
```

Thus your `*********` string reduces down to `*` and thus it matches the empty string...

Comment: this is perfect. I read as much documentation but didn't command-click the selector! Thanks!